# How to properly query a normalized database

Tags: mysql, database

I'm in the process of redesigning a MySQL database that has a table with about 1,500 columns, among other tables.  We want to normalize the data in this table by creating a second table that will have a record for each column/row that existed in the initial table.  Let's call these tables Master and MasterData.  Master will contain the basic information that all records in that table will require.  MasterData will contain the values for some additional data pertaining to records in the Master table.  So let's say Master will look like this:

```
MasterID     Property1     Property2
1            Yes           No
2            No            Yes
3            Yes           Yes
4            No            No
```

Let's say MasterData will look like this:

```
MasterID     Property     Value
1            Property3    Yes
1            Property4    No
3            Property3    No
4            Property7    Yes
```

With me so far?  How do I query this data and have only one row returned per matching Master row yet containing all related MasterData information.  I've searched and found a couple examples but they take too long to execute on our data.  I have created a test MasterData table based on the existing data in our one huge table mentioned earlier.  This results in MasterData having about 4.5 million records and the following queries simply take too long to execute and time out.

```
SELECT Property1, Property2, Master.MasterID,
    GROUP_CONCAT(case when Property = "Property3" then Value end) as Property3, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(case when Property = "Property7" then Value end) as Property7
FROM Master LEFT JOIN MasterData USING (MasterID) GROUP BY MasterID
HAVING Property3='Yes' OR Property7='Yes';
```

or

```
Select * FROM Master AS M, MasterData AS MD1, MasterData AS MD2 
WHERE M.MasterID=MD1.MasterID AND MD1.Property='Property3' AND MD1.Value='Yes' 
AND M.MasterID=MD2.MasterID AND MD2.VAR='Property7' AND MD2.Value='Yes';
```

Again, our goal is to be able to retrieve all data in MasterData in one row as if it were a column in Master.  Is this possible?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I'd prefer the second query over the first (although not with the implicit-join syntax), although I'd rather not use an EAV table like you're doing (there are a number of inherent issues).  1500 columns is way too many, though.  What's the scope of this data?  You probably have more multi-column tables, instead of what you've shown so far.

Comment: Can you specify the use case? I really wonder which problem should be solved by this approach.

Comment: That is not anormalized design, just so you know. Nor is it efficient or easy to query.

Comment: And you should NOT be using implicit joins in the 21st century. They are a SQL antipattern.

Comment: "Normalized". I do not think it means what you think it means.

Comment: Ok, so perhaps not correctly 'normalized' but at least more so, no?  Our problem is that we're running out of columns (properties) in the Master table and need a way to continue to add 'properties'.  What is the best way to do this?

Comment: We realize 1500 columns is not a good DB design so we're trying to do something about it.  Yes, we have other many-column tables that are also probably poor design but we're going to tackle one table at a time.  I am open to any suggestions you may have or links you could point me to.  Thx.

Answer (score 2):

> Again, our goal is to be able to retrieve all data in MasterData in one row as if it were a column in Master. Is this possible?

Without completely understanding your goal, I'm going to go out on a limb and say it's probably *possible*, strictly speaking. But it's not likely to be possible in any practical sense.  Performance will probably be abysmal in even the best case (just one or two properties); in the likely case (what, between 30 and 500 properties) you might take down the server altogether.

*Normalized* doesn't mean "creating a second table that will have a record for each column/row that existed in the initial table". It doesn't mean anything even remotely *like* that. But it's *possible* that normalization will actually solve your problem. (In my experience, most database problems are structural.)

What you have proposed here is a solution that isn't working well to a problem you haven't stated. To get the most out of the expertise on StackOverflow, state the problem you're trying to solve as well as the solutions you've tried.

[Wikipedia article about database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

---

If you start with a table like this . . .

```
create table master_data (
  master_id integer not null,
  property_name varchar(30) not null,
  property_value boolean not null default true,
  primary key (master_id, property_name)
);

insert into master_data values
(1, 'Property3', true),
(1, 'Property4', false),
(3, 'Property3', false),
(4, 'Property7', true);
```

. . . then you can get all the properties for all the things with a simple query.  (Assumes all your properties are Boolean.)

```
select * 
from master_data
order by master_id, property_name
--
1   Property3   t
1   Property4   f
3   Property3   f
4   Property7   t
```

Application code can loop over that pretty simply.  And you might be able to delete all the rows where property_value is false.

This structure allows an unlimited number of properties for each thing. But your requirements to a) return an arbitrary number of properties in a single row, and b) make minimal changes to application code have to change.  There's no way around that.

---

If your table contains these rows . . .

```
insert into master_data values
(1, 'Property3', true),
(1, 'Property4', false),
(3, 'Property3', false),
(4, 'Property7', true),
(1, 'Property7', true);
```

here's one way to get a set of "things" that qualify, and join that set to the table of master data.

```
select md.* 
from master_data md
inner join (select master_id
            from master_data
            where (
              (property_name = 'Property3' and property_value = true) or
              (property_name = 'Property7' and property_value = true)
            )
            group by master_id 
            having count(*) = 2 ) cd
  on (md.master_id = cd.master_id)
```

For what it's worth, normalization is still *probably* your best bet for long term maintenance and performance. This kind of structure (above) is not normalized; performance is generally poor with large sets of data. (PostgreSQL with the optional hstore module might be better than MySQL at this.)

Comment: This is my first post on Stackoverflow and I'm not quite sure how the comments work but I'll repeat what I just wrote above.  Our problem is that we're running out of columns (properties) in the Master table and need a way to continue to add 'properties'. What is the best way to do this?  I understand this isn't the definition of 'normalized' but I've seen this technique used in ecommerce web apps before so we thought we'd try it here.  I'm definitely open to any other suggestions you may have or links you could point me to.

Comment: [MySQL has column and row size limits.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/column-count-limit.html) AFAIK, no SQL dbms supports continuously adding columns forever.  You *might* be able to add another table with basically the same structure and exactly the same primary key data type (not autonumber, though) and link them with a foreign key constraint (with INNODB, not with MyISAM). That would give you a bunch of columns you could use in the second table, but I'd consider this a Band-Aid, not a solution. (JOIN the two tables at run time; don't exceed column or row size limits, though.)

Comment: Agreed.  I think a 2nd table of similar structure would be a band-aid.  We could hit a column limit on the second table and this problem would arise once again and we would then have to go into the code and adjust all of the queries...again.  Can you think of a 'solution' to this problem?  Is there anything I could further explain?

Comment: What is it that requires one row of 1500+ columns on output? Whatever that thing is--that seems to be your real problem.

Comment: Yes, that is the real problem and the one we're trying to fix.  Each row in Master is a record pertaining to an individual thing.  Each column is a property to that thing.  Some of these things have 1500 (and growing) properties.  Sometimes we return just one thing with it's properties and sometimes we return 1000's of things with their properties.  We're trying to keep the individual queries or connections to the DB to a minimum.  Querying the MasterData table once for each thing would drastically increase the number of queries so we were trying to avoid that.

Comment: Why do all the properties for one thing have to be in a single row?

Comment: I'm not sure they HAVE to be but we sometimes query 1000's of things and it's easier to deal with if all properties pertaining to one thing are in the same row.  Then we can loop through the results and each loop is for 1 thing.  Any alternative would likely require much more processing post query and we'd like to keep as much of our code (Perl) unchanged as possible.

Comment: You can keep all your Perl code unchanged. Just keep doing things the way you're doing them now.

Comment: How do you mean?  We can't continue doing things the way we are now because we're running out of columns in the Master table.

Comment: @user715446: That was kind of my point. You can't keep returning every possible property for a thing in one row, and so you also can't keep your Perl code unchanged. I'll add something to my answer in 10 minutes or so.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback and I understand what you are saying but consider this...  We want to query and return 3,000 things from the Master table and display some of their properties.  If we can't return all of the properties for a given thing in a single row we would have to query for each thing's properties separately, upping the query count from 1 to 3,001, right?  We don't want 3001 queries for one page.  How would you handle this scenario?

Comment: @user715446: No, you can get every property for every "thing" with a single query. (Near the end of my answer above.) No matter how many things you want, the database can return all their properties from a single query.

Comment: How would you do that?  Query1: Get list of 'things' that qualify. ie. "Property3 = 'Value3' and Property7 = 'Value7'".  Loop through results building WHERE clause for second query.  Query2: Get all desired properties for 'things' returned from first query, order by MasterID.  Loop through results creating a 2 dimensional hash. Is that what you had in mind? Other suggestions?

Comment: Get a set of "things" that qualify, and join that set to the table of master data. (That's one query.) Application code loops through the result set to create any kind of data structure you want.

Comment: Thank you Catcall.  Would that be using a sub-query?  Could you show me an example of such a query?